# JQuery load() fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var na = $("#navDivA");
var nb = $("#navDivB");
var ca = $("#contentA");
var cb = $("#contentB");
var la = $("#home");
var lb = $("#about");
var firstSession = true;

na.on("click", function () {
    ca.load("home.html", function(){
         alert("Loaded");
       });
   });

nb.on("click", function () {
    cb.load("about.html");
   });
}); 

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navDivA"><a id="home">Home</a></div>
    <div id="navDivB"><a id="about">About</a></div>
    <div id="contentA"></div>
    <div id="contentB"></div>
 </div>
```

Why does it alert multiple times every time I start to click? How can I avoid this? I want to load the html file once.

Comment: Multipe times per click or just one time each click? Maybe you are looking for `one()` Anyway,  your question is missing context to make it clear

Comment: Could you also provide the HTML that goes with this script?

Comment: At the first click it fires once, but at the second he goes 3 times and and the third click he goes multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `on`. According to documentation

> The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

which seems to be what you need. Change the code to

```
na.one("click", function () {
    ca.load("home.html", function(){
         alert("Loaded");
    });
});

nb.one("click", function () {
    cb.load("about.html");
});
```

Comment: Ty for answer, but it doest work. He still fires the method multiple times.

Comment: @AntonStyopin Could you create [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I tried this code in jsFiddle and it worked fine. But in my code it doesnt. I think it might be because of the .html file inside the load()-function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xmtsu3nb/16/   ... Here the one() function works but in my case he alerts multiple times after a few clicks

Comment: @AntonStyopin Could it be that you have more that one element with `id="contentA"` on your page? Unfortunately if we can't see reproduced issue in jsFiddle or similar service there is not much we can help with

Comment: I found the issue! in my home.html and in my about.html is a <html><body>... tagged. This causes error. I deletet all this and just putted a <div> into the home and about.html and it works! Tanks for answer.